# Is there a complete metalanguage?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, metalanguage

Just asking a rather simple question, but my search in google was.. unsuccessful. I'm searching right now for a programming metalanguage who'd be complete. In short, is there any such language in which every other programming language (java, c, anything else) could be expressed ? Including all the vocabulary and all the concepts that could be found in any other language. Such as classes, functions, methods, thread, etc.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Any sufficiently powerful metalanguage qualifies - Forth, Common Lisp, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Type-0 grammars include all formal grammars. They generate exactly all languages that can be recognized by a Turing machine.

Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy